# Asynchronous call in spring with EhCache

Tags: spring, asynchronous, ehcache

I am trying to load data from database when I call evict cache. I have used spring thread pool executor and **@async** annotation. I have enabled the Asynchronous in my servlet xml. When I hit the rest API, it start the execution of task executor and it runs perfectly. 
**But the issue is object are not cached**. I have use standard query EhCache for caching. When I hit the API call for same data, it is firing a DB call and load data from DB not from cache. Meanwhile when I hit same API twice it picked data from cache.

I am not sure why async function not able to load object in cache. However i have checked the tmp folder where actually cache saved in files and it seems its storing the objects there.

Can any one help me to fix this problem??

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: Please add versions, sample code and configuration. Otherwise this is going to be a guess game.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported an issue with `@ASync` and `@Cacheable` not working together.

See [SPR-15915](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15915). It might be your current problem,